# Get likes/dislikes from a youtube video with Zend Framework PHP

Tags: api, zend-framework, youtube

I'm unable to find any documentation where I can find a code example for receiving the likes and dislikes of a video.
That's my current code:

```
$videoId = 'AyJl2NyQ0hI';
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($videoId);

echo "Views: <strong>".$videoEntry->getVideoViewCount()."</strong><br />";
```

It works fine, but who to get the likes/dislikes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just look through the source for classes `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry` and `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_Statistics`:

```
$videoEntry->getStatistics()->getViewCount();
```

Edit: You edited your question and you are now looking for Likes/Dislikes

Step 1: Change the protocol version to v2

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
```

Step 2: The last stable release of the zend gdata youtube client is missing methods to access the likes and dislikes, but the data is returned. You can get at it by looking through the extension attributes of the Rating extension:

```
$videoId = 'AyJl2NyQ0hI';
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry($videoId);

foreach ($videoEntry->getExtensionElements() as $extension)
{
    if ($extension->rootElement == 'rating')
    {
        $attributes = $extension->getExtensionAttributes();
        var_dump($attributes);
    }
}
```

Which should return:

```
array(2) {
  ["numDislikes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["namespaceUri"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "numDislikes"
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "57"
  }
  ["numLikes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["namespaceUri"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "numLikes"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "657"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd add to this that if the OP switches to an auto-completing IDE, this stuff would probably be clear without even checking the docs.

Comment: Still there is no way to get the likes/dislikes. I'm only able to fetch the old rating (with stars from 1-5).

Comment: Updated my answer. You will have to hack zf trunk if you want to get at these directly through a method.